# How to move powertools items to my store

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

```
website.powertools.http=http://powertools.local:9001/mystorefront
website.powertools.https=https://powertools.local:9002/mystorefront

website.mystore.http=http://localhost:9002
website.mystore.https=https://localhost:900
```

those are from localproperties.

so now, when i go to

https://localhost:9002

storefront comes. when i click something, it goes to

https://localhost:9002/powertools/en/USD/Open-Catalogue/Tools/Measuring-%26-Layout-Tools/c/1358

i want to remove this powertools and make it mystore.

What should i do?

I did not configure powertools, it is coming from b2b.

I also did not configure mystore.

I just want powertools to become mystore.

also on project properties, i did

```
mystorefront.webroot=
storefrontContextRoot=
```

this to make localhost navigate to mystore.

i also used that impex and i can see in in wcms / websites

```
$siteUid=mystore       

# CMS Site                                                                                                 
INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite ; uid[unique=true] ; urlPatterns                                                                                                                  ;      
                      ; $siteUid         ; (?i)^https?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=$siteUid)(|\&.*)$,(?i)^https?://$siteUid\.[^/]+(|/.*|\?.*)$,(?i)^https?://[^/].*$ ;
```

Comment: How did you configure mystore? What are die URL Patterns for mystore and powertools site? Do you have URL attributes configured for mystore/powertools site? How can you tell the difference between mystore and powertools sites?

Comment: @JohannesNolte 
I did not configure powertools, it is coming from b2b.

I also did not configure mystore.

I just want powertools to become mystore. 


also on project properties, i did 


   `mystorefront.webroot=
    storefrontContextRoot=`

this to make localhost navigate to `mystore.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An accelerator module is able to display more than one CMS Site. A CMS Site is the configuration item for your online shop frontend. It is stored in the database. The accelerator module is just the source code that takes care of displaying a CMS Site. What products/pages are displayed and what languages, designs and so on are supported is configured in the CMS Site. Also, a CMS Site holds URL Patterns, which are regular expressions. If the request URL matches one of the URL Patterns, it is considered to belong to the corresponding CMS Site.

Did you configure a CMS Site for mystore? Creating a CMS Site requires the creation a lot of related types and has a lot of pitfalls. I would recommend you to follow the commmerce trail on the hybris help pages to create your own accelerator module/CMS Site config.

Comment: i  used that impex and i can see in in wcms / websites

   `$siteUid=mystore       
    
    # CMS Site                                                                                                 
    INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite ; uid[unique=true] ; urlPatterns                                                                                                                  ;      
                          ; $siteUid         ; (?i)^https?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=$siteUid)(|\&.*)$,(?i)^https?://$siteUid\.[^/]+(|/.*|\?.*)$,(?i)^https?://[^/].*$ ;`

Comment: There is already a configure for powertools. I want to use it as mystore. i disabled wcms/websites for powertools and added for mystore which i mentioned top
When i change powertools wcms/websites to active and change preview to mystore then.  When i go to localhost,it opens powertools without changing url but when i click, url changes https://localhost:9002/powertools/en/USD/Open-Catalogue/Tools/Power-Drills/c/1360 there is no mystore in the url.

Comment: Have a look at the attribute "URL Encoding Attributes" of your site. There should be the following: storefront,language,currency. URL Encoding Attributes are attributes, that are added to the URL as so called Context Path. This context path is added to the URL after the extension root and the page urls. So the missing part in the middle are the URL Encoding Attriubes: /powertools/en/USD. As configured, these are the name of your store (storefront as name is misleading here), language isocode and currency isocode. If you delete those URL Encoding attributes, they are gone form the URL.

Comment: As an alternative you can rename the store powertools to mystore. Don't confuse store with site. Store is the economic view of your accelerator (like currency, delivery methods, payment methods...), site more the technical view (like url patterns, content catalogs, product catalogs...).

Comment: Just a piece of advice: I'm almost certain, that at some point you will need to create your own accelerator module. In that case your current efforts are in vain. That's why I mentioned the hybris commerce trails.

Comment: i want to build my store on powertools.